# how to ignore Aero Peek on specific win32 app

Tags: c++, winapi

this is background my problem.(why I make win32 toy program)

I'm making OTT-viewer by using Electron.

I implemented PiP(Picture in Picture) feature by suing `setAlwaysOnTop` method.

It works well in general situation,

But When I use Aero Peek(I don't know exactly what is it called, Hover mouse to live preview at taskbar) mode,

my guess is that DWM hides my App as transparently.

https://youtu.be/r0UKwrykMGs (this is video about my explanation)

My Purpose is that when I use PiP  or always on Top Mode,

any program even window manager doesn't disturb my program.

I don't mean disable whole Aero Peek feature. only this PiP program.

(Is it possible? some article says that only way is disable aero peek.)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

In above reason, so I build toy program in c++.

it is just default windows desktop template code. I just modified `InitInstance` function.

```cpp
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; 

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   

// I added this below code 
   SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 300, 300, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
   BOOL ani = TRUE;

   DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY t = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
   
HRESULT res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &t, sizeof(t));
    res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &ani, sizeof(ani));
    res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT, &ani, sizeof(ani));
    res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT, &ani, sizeof(ani));

   if (SUCCEEDED(res))
   {
       int msgboxID = MessageBox(
           NULL,
           L"temp.txt already exists.\nDo you want to replace it?",
           L"Confirm Save As",
           MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO
       );

   }
////////


   return TRUE;
}
```

and I changed DWM attribute, enable or disable rendering features. but nothing to happened.

what I'm doing is impossible in windows?

thank you for reading.

check electron docs and win32 DWM docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/api/dwmapi)

Comment: `DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK`?

Comment: @RaymondChen I missed that. it is clearly works. thank you Mr.chen!

Comment: @fabyday You can make it as answer for completion of the question.